# sql Contains query doesn't return a known answer

Tags: sql, sql-server

*Context: this is a section I have cut out of a much larger stored Proc and found this is the part that is causing my error.*

I have a table of data, put very simply it contains 2 records:

```
[Title]
Mitchell
Andrew
```

and I have a super simple query:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  [Title]
  FROM [Post] p
  where  CONTAINS (p.Title, '"Andrew"' )
```

This return 1 row successfully (this shows whatever indexing on this column needs to be there does work), however:

```
SELECT TOP 1 
  [Title]     
FROM [Post] p
where  CONTAINS (p.Title, '"Mitchell"' )
```

does not return any rows.

I know it is selectable because this does return the row:

```
SELECT TOP 1   
  [Title]    
FROM [Post] p
where title like 'Mitchell'
```

I think the data is in error, because when I run this on a local backup of the database it returns the row fine.

So my question is what else can I do to investigate the fault?

Currently tried rebuilding indexes (although this column isn't explicitly indexed)

Comment: would you please set up a http://sqlfiddle.com/ to demonstrate?

Comment: Your contains query has double quotes around Mitchell and your select top 1 does not.

Comment: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ea42f6 sqlFiddle as requested. @blur0224 it does not return with or without the double quotes for Mitchell, however both do return for Andrew

Comment: This column *should* be indexed, since `CONTAINS` queries the full-text index -- but this index is built in the background, so there might be something wrong there. Verify the full-text index daemon (fdhost) is running; [repopulate](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms142575) if necessary.

Comment: Are you certain there are no unprintable characters around `Mitchell` in the table?

Comment: The backup would appear to be out-of-sync with the production database.  Does the `LIKE` version return anything on the production system?

Comment: Hmm, clearly an issue on your side - I can't reproduce it. Try to re-create the full-text index. Check the server logs for errors. Re-create the table as a copy -  SELECT * INTO test FROM Post; Create the full-text index on the copy table and try the queries there. These steps might help you track down the issue. Good luck!

Comment: how about something like: select top 1 from (select * from p where title like 'Andrew') ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the input guys,

I had ran the indexes on the individual table but not rebuild [the full text index](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb326036(v=sql.105).aspx) catalogs using the following command:

```
ALTER FULLTEXT CATALOG [PostCatalog] REBUILD
```

After this completed, I can find both Andrew and Mitchell.

I think the reason I couldn't replicate locally is that when I restored the database, it rebuild it automatically.

Cheers guys

Answer (score 0):

You appear to be using `CONTAINS` incorrectly.  According to the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187787.aspx), the searched-for text is a **word**, meaning *a string of characters without spaces or punctuation*.  Thus `'"Mitchell"'` is invalid as a search term.  The surprise is not that it returns no rows, but that `'"Andrew"'` does.

Do you need `CONTAINS`, with all its complexity?  The data you provide (which I understand is simplified) doesn't even require pattern-matching, let alone matching inflected forms and synonyms.  (`Andrew` and `Mitchell` don't have inflected forms or synonyms.)  A simple `=` would suffice.

So, the answer is, you're doing it wrong.  If `CONTAINS` isn't needed, simplify your query and your life by using something more direct.  And, whether it is or isn't, provide a search term consistent with the data and semantics of the function you're using.